# Javascript Convert Date Time string to Epoch

Tags: javascript, datetime, epoch

so I give up...been trying to do this all day;

I have a string that supplies a date and time in the format `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm` (`04/12/2012 07:00`).

I need to turn that into an Epoch date so I can do some calculations upon it. I cannot modify the format in which the date time is sent to me.

JavaScript or jQuery is fine.

Comment: `new Date('04/12/2012 07:00')`?

Comment: Thanks Rocket, but that would give me April 12th and I want Dec 4th.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting UTC string to epoch time in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680025/converting-utc-string-to-epoch-time-in-javascript)

Comment: uhhhh.... @cbm64 you mean `new Date('12/04/2012 07:00')` . ...?

Comment: @cbm64 Hi, I'm facing the same issue. But in my case I only have date not time. New Date for mm/dd/yyyy is working, but I want to use dd/mm/yyyy . If  it is new Date(dd/mm/yyyy) giving invalid date. Could you pls pls tell me how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[JavaScript dates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) are internally stored as milliseconds since epoch. You just need to convert it to a number, e.g. with the unary `+` operator, to get them. Or you can use the [`.getTime` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

The harder will be parsing your date string. You likely will use a regex to extract the values from your string and pass them into [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```
var parts = datestring.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
return Date.UTC(+parts[3], parts[2]-1, +parts[1], +parts[4], +parts[5]);
```

This will yield `1354604400000 ms` for your example date.

Comment: The reason he's subtracting 1 from the month field is months are based on 0 index. Which means January is "0". NOT 1. And December is 11. NOT 12. Weird but true.

Comment: This is way over complicated. `Math.floor(new Date('12/04/2012 07:00') / 1000)` works exactly fine. You might need to do a little string manipulation to flip the month and day values around but that's not a problem and it's still simpler code than what you've got here.

Comment: @John no, it does not work exactly fine, there are many browsers disagreeing on how to interpret that format, and whether it represents `07:00` in UTC or `07:00` in the local timezone.

Comment: @Bergi I never considered that something so fundamental would not be consistent across the web. Would that then mean that one needs to collect the users locale in order to determine if the datetime is in UTC? Or, could one only ever use the server to set timestamps and let the browser interpret their local time based on a user locale setting? I guess as long as all your timestamps are based off the same server time, the user setting their locale is really all that needs to happen. Is there something else I'd be missing in this approach?

Comment: @John Yes, UTC timestamps (integers) are the preferred format for transporting dates between server and client. Alternatively use ISO 8601 strings with a timezone designator, browsers that don't support these died out since I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 62):

```
var someDate = new Date(dateString);
someDate = someDate.getTime();
```

Comment: Nice try but as in the format above that will turn Dec 04 into April 12 (Thu Apr 12 07:00:00 UTC+0100 2012).

Comment: hmm okay...so you why can't you modify the format sent to you? I can understand if you can't modify the original value sent to you, but can't you reformat it after you get it? If so, you can `.split` at space and then `/` and `:` and get the parts and reorder them to a format recognized by the `new Date()`

Comment: I cannot modify the string input because it is sent from a database in that format. I used solution from Bergi but thanks for the response!

Comment: Okay well in principle, he did exactly what I was talking about...taking the string and reordering the parts to a format recognized by the js functions.  Happy to hear you got your answer!

Answer (score 48):

You can use `Date.parse(date)`.

```
function epoch (date) {
  return Date.parse(date)
}

const dateToday = new Date() // Mon Jun 08 2020 16:47:55 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
const timestamp = epoch(dateToday)

console.log(timestamp) // => 1591606075000
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the momentjs library to do this rather easily.

```
var epoch = moment(str).unix();
```

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 9):

i used this code to convert my string datetime to epoch

```
new Date(<datetime string>').getTime()
```

for example :

```
let epoch = new Date('2016-10-11').getTime()
```

Comment: seems to be missing a dependency definition - `Fatal error: Date(...).getTime is not a function`

Comment: Thnaks ! is very usefull

Answer (score 9):

```
Number(new Date('04/12/2012 07:00'))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var time = new Date().getTime() / 1000 + 900 + 330*60;

console.log("time = "+time);
```

getTime() will return current time with milleseconds in last 3 digit so divide it by 1000 first. Now I have added 900 means 15 min which I need from my current time(You can delete if you do not require further delay time), 330*60(5 hr 30) is required to convert GMT time to IST which is my current region time.

Use below site to test your time :-

https://www.epochconverter.com/

[image]

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 4):

Since your date format is dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm, you will need to change the date format (Step 1). Else you can go to (Step 2).

Step 1. Change Date Format to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm

```
  var currentTime   = "21/02/2021 12:00"
  var monthPosition = currentTime.split('/', 2).join('/').length
  var day           = currentTime.substring(0, currentTime.indexOf('/'))
  var month         = currentTime.substring(currentTime.indexOf('/') + 1, monthPosition);
  var time          = month + "/" + day + currentTime.substring(month.length + day.length  + 1); //"02/21/2021 12:00"
```

Step 2: Change Date to Epoch Time

```
var epochTime = Date.parse(time);

//or get current time of epoch time
var currentEpoch = Date.parse(new Date());
```

Note: If you trying to do Date.parse() with new Date(), and got an error of parsing date string, add toString()

```
var currentEpoch = Date.parse(new Date().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to convert current time to epoch time using JavaScript

const **currentDate** = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);

console.log(**currentDate**); //whatever value it will print you can check the same value to this website https://www.epochconverter.com/ to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I found this line from [jslint](https://www.jslint.com/) code.

https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint/blob/a286a254f3312108cf64553914b99a642af0ac42/asset_codemirror_rollup.js#L268

```
+new Date
```

It's pretty obvious that this is [Douglas Crockford](https://github.com/douglascrockford) way.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest way to do is -**

```
const moment = require('moment')


 function getUnixTime () { return this.getTime() / 1000 | 0 }
let epochDateTime = getUnixTime(new Date(moment().add(365, 'days').format('YYYY- 
MM-DD hh:mm:ss')))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Single Line Code**
Returns in seconds

`let Epoch= Date.parse(date + '') / 1000  //date in Date() Format`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
Math.trunc(new Date(date).getTime()/1000)
```

result

```
1671878316
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const myDate = new Date("2023-04-15"); // create a new Date object with a specified date
const epochTime = myDate.getTime() / 1000; // divide by 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds
console.log(epochTime); // output: 1687974000 (the epoch time for the specified date)
```

In this example, we first create a new Date object with a specified date using the new Date() constructor. We then call the getTime() method on the myDate object to get the time in milliseconds since the Unix epoch (January 1, 1970). Finally, we divide the result by 1000 to convert it to seconds, which is the format commonly used for epoch time.

Comment: Using ChatGPT to post answers is forbidden. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned