# converting datetime into Date object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I convert the below string into a Date object in JavaScript and JQuery and display it. 
31/08/2016 10:40 AM

I tried the below approach but it works when I provide only date. I want to work with time too

```
      <div id = "datepicker">31/08/2016</div>

     var numbers= $("#datepicker").text().split("/");
    var date = new Date(numbers[2], numbers[1], numbers[0]);
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = date

         How should I get the Date() object when I provide a div like below

    <div id = "datepicker">31/08/2016 10:40 AM</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Convert Date Time string to Epoch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707333/javascript-convert-date-time-string-to-epoch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which is the de-facto standard library for date and time handling in JavaScript.

It is [a lot more intuitive and consistent across browsers than JavaScript's native DateTime API](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/):

```js
var myDate = moment("31/08/2016 10:40 AM", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A")
console.log(myDate) // "2016-08-31T14:40:00.000Z"
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem lies here

```
var date = new Date(numbers[2], numbers[1], numbers[0]);
```

You never tell the browser to split for the space in between the date and time. So `numbers[2]` is going to return `2016 10:40 AM` which obviously does not fit the parameters of a new Date object.