# Getting Total Seconds From Date Timestamps

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs

I am trying to get the total seconds from 2 timestamps. I am currently getting the total days, hours and minutes, but I am trying to get all the way to the second. I am unable to find the formula...

Can someone point me in the right direction of getting the seconds too, along with the days, hours and minutes that I have already accomplished.

Here is my code thus far:

```
//gets timestamps
var clockedIn = "2017-03-02 09:45:25";
var clockedOut = "2017-03-04 09:49:06";

//sets timestamps to vars
var now  = clockedIn;
var then = clockedOut;
var diff = moment.duration(moment(then).diff(moment(now)));

//parses out times
var days = parseInt(diff.asDays());
var hours = parseInt(diff.asHours());
hours = (hours - days * 24);
var minutes = parseInt(diff.asMinutes());
minutes = minutes - (days * 24 * 60 + hours * 60);

//I am looking to get seconds here...
```

Any help would be appreciated, even if it is just a link.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Convert Date Time string to Epoch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707333/javascript-convert-date-time-string-to-epoch)

Comment: I am not seeing any useful info in the link @DynoFu

Comment: i thought you were using the vanilla javascript. parse the timestamp string and use Date.getTime() you have the epoc and then do the calculation. Icid has the right answer. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this function? [`seconds()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/)

Comment: No, I should have explained further. I am looking for an output like: 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes and 54 seconds. I am currently getting the 1 day, 2 hours, 3 minutes portion, but not the seconds portion

Comment: Oh ok, then it's `seconds()` you need.

Answer (score 4):

One simple solution is to create two Date objects and get the difference between them.

```
var clockedIn = new Date("2017-03-02 09:45:25");
var clockedOut = new Date("2017-03-04 09:49:06");

var seconds = (clockedOut-clockedIn)/1000 
// divide by 1000 because the difference we get will be in milliseconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use any complex method to calculate the difference of the two moment (or Date) objects. Simply calculating the difference gives you the total difference between the two dates in milliseconds.

```
var now = moment();
var then = moment().add(1231, 'second'); // just to have an example different date

var milliseconds = +then - +now;
var seconds = milliseconds / 1000;
var minutes = seconds / 60;
var hours = minutes / 60;
```

If you would like to get the difference formatted like `HH:mm:ss`, just convert the diff milliseconds back to moment object and use [.format()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/):

```
var now = moment();
var then = moment().add(1231, 'second'); // just to have an example different date

var diff_m = moment(+then - +now);
console.log(diff_m.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice plugin for momentjs available on github that makes this kind of formating very nice, as you can simply specify a `format` for your duration. https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

```js
var clockedIn = "2017-03-02 09:45:25";
var clockedOut = "2017-03-04 09:49:06";

//sets timestamps to vars
var now  = clockedIn;
var then = clockedOut;
var diff = moment.duration(moment(then).diff(moment(now)));

console.log(diff.format("d [days], H [hours], m [minutes] [and] s [seconds] "));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*! Moment Duration Format v1.3.0
 *  https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format 
 *  Date: 2014-07-15
 *
 *  Duration format plugin function for the Moment.js library
 *  http://momentjs.com/
 *
 *  Copyright 2014 John Madhavan-Reese
 *  Released under the MIT license
 */

(function (root, undefined) {

 // repeatZero(qty)
 // returns "0" repeated qty times
 function repeatZero(qty) {
  var result = "";
  
  // exit early
  // if qty is 0 or a negative number
  // or doesn't coerce to an integer
  qty = parseInt(qty, 10);
  if (!qty || qty < 1) { return result; }
  
  while (qty) {
   result += "0";
   qty -= 1;
  }
  
  return result;
 }
 
 // padZero(str, len [, isRight])
 // pads a string with zeros up to a specified length
 // will not pad a string if its length is aready
 // greater than or equal to the specified length
 // default output pads with zeros on the left
 // set isRight to `true` to pad with zeros on the right
 function padZero(str, len, isRight) {
  if (str == null) { str = ""; }
  str = "" + str;
  
  return (isRight ? str : "") + repeatZero(len - str.length) + (isRight ? "" : str);
 }
 
 // isArray
 function isArray(array) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(array) === "[object Array]";
 }
 
 // isObject
 function isObject(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Object]";
 }
 
 // findLast
 function findLast(array, callback) {
  var index = array.length;

  while (index -= 1) {
   if (callback(array[index])) { return array[index]; }
  }
 }

 // find
 function find(array, callback) {
  var index = 0,
   max = array.length,
   match;
   
  if (typeof callback !== "function") {
   match = callback;
   callback = function (item) {
    return item === match;
   };
  }

  while (index < max) {
   if (callback(array[index])) { return array[index]; }
   index += 1;
  }
 }
 
 // each
 function each(array, callback) {
  var index = 0,
   max = array.length;
   
  if (!array || !max) { return; }

  while (index < max) {
   if (callback(array[index], index) === false) { return; }
   index += 1;
  }
 }
 
 // map
 function map(array, callback) {
  var index = 0,
   max = array.length,
   ret = [];

  if (!array || !max) { return ret; }
    
  while (index < max) {
   ret[index] = callback(array[index], index);
   index += 1;
  }
  
  return ret;
 }
 
 // pluck
 function pluck(array, prop) {
  return map(array, function (item) {
   return item[prop];
  });
 }
 
 // compact
 function compact(array) {
  var ret = [];
  
  each(array, function (item) {
   if (item) { ret.push(item); }
  });
  
  return ret;
 }
 
 // unique
 function unique(array) {
  var ret = [];
  
  each(array, function (_a) {
   if (!find(ret, _a)) { ret.push(_a); }
  });
  
  return ret;
 }
 
 // intersection
 function intersection(a, b) {
  var ret = [];
  
  each(a, function (_a) {
   each(b, function (_b) {
    if (_a === _b) { ret.push(_a); }
   });
  });
  
  return unique(ret);
 }
 
 // rest
 function rest(array, callback) {
  var ret = [];
  
  each(array, function (item, index) {
   if (!callback(item)) {
    ret = array.slice(index);
    return false;
   }
  });
  
  return ret;
 }

 // initial
 function initial(array, callback) {
  var reversed = array.slice().reverse();
  
  return rest(reversed, callback).reverse();
 }
 
 // extend
 function extend(a, b) {
  for (var key in b) {
   if (b.hasOwnProperty(key)) { a[key] = b[key]; }
  }
  
  return a;
 }
   
 // define internal moment reference
 var moment;

 if (typeof require === "function") {
  try { moment = require('moment'); } 
  catch (e) {}
 } 
 
 if (!moment && root.moment) {
  moment = root.moment;
 }
 
 if (!moment) {
  throw "Moment Duration Format cannot find Moment.js";
 }
 
 // moment.duration.format([template] [, precision] [, settings])
 moment.duration.fn.format = function () {

  var tokenizer, tokens, types, typeMap, momentTypes, foundFirst, trimIndex,
   args = [].slice.call(arguments),
   settings = extend({}, this.format.defaults),
   // keep a shadow copy of this moment for calculating remainders
   remainder = moment.duration(this);

  // add a reference to this duration object to the settings for use
  // in a template function
  settings.duration = this;

  // parse arguments
  each(args, function (arg) {
   if (typeof arg === "string" || typeof arg === "function") {
    settings.template = arg;
    return;
   }

   if (typeof arg === "number") {
    settings.precision = arg;
    return;
   }

   if (isObject(arg)) {
    extend(settings, arg);
   }
  });

  // types
  types = settings.types = (isArray(settings.types) ? settings.types : settings.types.split(" "));

  // template
  if (typeof settings.template === "function") {
   settings.template = settings.template.apply(settings);
  }

  // tokenizer regexp
  tokenizer = new RegExp(map(types, function (type) {
   return settings[type].source;
  }).join("|"), "g");

  // token type map function
  typeMap = function (token) {
   return find(types, function (type) {
    return settings[type].test(token);
   });
  };

  // tokens array
  tokens = map(settings.template.match(tokenizer), function (token, index) {
   var type = typeMap(token),
    length = token.length;

   return {
    index: index,
    length: length,

    // replace escaped tokens with the non-escaped token text
    token: (type === "escape" ? token.replace(settings.escape, "$1") : token),

    // ignore type on non-moment tokens
    type: ((type === "escape" || type === "general") ? null : type)

    // calculate base value for all moment tokens
    //baseValue: ((type === "escape" || type === "general") ? null : this.as(type))
   };
  }, this);

  // unique moment token types in the template (in order of descending magnitude)
  momentTypes = intersection(types, unique(compact(pluck(tokens, "type"))));

  // exit early if there are no momentTypes
  if (!momentTypes.length) {
   return pluck(tokens, "token").join("");
  }

  // calculate values for each token type in the template
  each(momentTypes, function (momentType, index) {
   var value, wholeValue, decimalValue, isLeast, isMost;

   // calculate integer and decimal value portions
   value = remainder.as(momentType);
   wholeValue = (value > 0 ? Math.floor(value) : Math.ceil(value));
   decimalValue = value - wholeValue;

   // is this the least-significant moment token found?
   isLeast = ((index + 1) === momentTypes.length);

   // is this the most-significant moment token found?
   isMost = (!index);

   // update tokens array
   // using this algorithm to not assume anything about
   // the order or frequency of any tokens
   each(tokens, function (token) {
    if (token.type === momentType) {
     extend(token, {
      value: value,
      wholeValue: wholeValue,
      decimalValue: decimalValue,
      isLeast: isLeast,
      isMost: isMost
     });

     if (isMost) {
      // note the length of the most-significant moment token:
      // if it is greater than one and forceLength is not set, default forceLength to `true`
      if (settings.forceLength == null && token.length > 1) {
       settings.forceLength = true;
      }

      // rationale is this:
      // if the template is "h:mm:ss" and the moment value is 5 minutes, the user-friendly output is "5:00", not "05:00"
      // shouldn't pad the `minutes` token even though it has length of two
      // if the template is "hh:mm:ss", the user clearly wanted everything padded so we should output "05:00"
      // if the user wanted the full padded output, they can set `{ trim: false }` to get "00:05:00"
     }
    }
   });

   // update remainder
   remainder.subtract(wholeValue, momentType);
  });
 
  // trim tokens array
  if (settings.trim) {
   tokens = (settings.trim === "left" ? rest : initial)(tokens, function (token) {
    // return `true` if:
    // the token is not the least moment token (don't trim the least moment token)
    // the token is a moment token that does not have a value (don't trim moment tokens that have a whole value)
    return !(token.isLeast || (token.type != null && token.wholeValue));
   });
  }
  
  
  // build output

  // the first moment token can have special handling
  foundFirst = false;

  // run the map in reverse order if trimming from the right
  if (settings.trim === "right") {
   tokens.reverse();
  }

  tokens = map(tokens, function (token) {
   var val,
    decVal;

   if (!token.type) {
    // if it is not a moment token, use the token as its own value
    return token.token;
   }

   // apply negative precision formatting to the least-significant moment token
   if (token.isLeast && (settings.precision < 0)) {
    val = (Math.floor(token.wholeValue * Math.pow(10, settings.precision)) * Math.pow(10, -settings.precision)).toString();
   } else {
    val = token.wholeValue.toString();
   }
   
   // remove negative sign from the beginning
   val = val.replace(/^\-/, "");

   // apply token length formatting
   // special handling for the first moment token that is not the most significant in a trimmed template
   if (token.length > 1 && (foundFirst || token.isMost || settings.forceLength)) {
    val = padZero(val, token.length);
   }

   // add decimal value if precision > 0
   if (token.isLeast && (settings.precision > 0)) {
    decVal = token.decimalValue.toString().replace(/^\-/, "").split(/\.|e\-/);
    switch (decVal.length) {
     case 1:
      val += "." + padZero(decVal[0], settings.precision, true).slice(0, settings.precision);
      break;
      
     case 2:
      val += "." + padZero(decVal[1], settings.precision, true).slice(0, settings.precision);  
      break;
      
     case 3:
      val += "." + padZero(repeatZero((+decVal[2]) - 1) + (decVal[0] || "0") + decVal[1], settings.precision, true).slice(0, settings.precision);  
      break;
     
     default:
      throw "Moment Duration Format: unable to parse token decimal value.";
    }
   }
   
   // add a negative sign if the value is negative and token is most significant
   if (token.isMost && token.value < 0) {
    val = "-" + val;
   }

   foundFirst = true;

   return val;
  });

  // undo the reverse if trimming from the right
  if (settings.trim === "right") {
   tokens.reverse();
  }

  return tokens.join("");
 };

 moment.duration.fn.format.defaults = {
  // token definitions
  escape: /\[(.+?)\]/,
  years: /[Yy]+/,
  months: /M+/,
  weeks: /[Ww]+/,
  days: /[Dd]+/,
  hours: /[Hh]+/,
  minutes: /m+/,
  seconds: /s+/,
  milliseconds: /S+/,
  general: /.+?/,

  // token type names
  // in order of descending magnitude
  // can be a space-separated token name list or an array of token names
  types: "escape years months weeks days hours minutes seconds milliseconds general",

  // format options

  // trim
  // "left" - template tokens are trimmed from the left until the first moment token that has a value >= 1
  // "right" - template tokens are trimmed from the right until the first moment token that has a value >= 1
  // (the final moment token is not trimmed, regardless of value)
  // `false` - template tokens are not trimmed
  trim: "left",

  // precision
  // number of decimal digits to include after (to the right of) the decimal point (positive integer)
  // or the number of digits to truncate to 0 before (to the left of) the decimal point (negative integer)
  precision: 0,

  // force first moment token with a value to render at full length even when template is trimmed and first moment token has length of 1
  forceLength: null,

  // template used to format duration
  // may be a function or a string
  // template functions are executed with the `this` binding of the settings object
  // so that template strings may be dynamically generated based on the duration object
  // (accessible via `this.duration`)
  // or any of the other settings
  template: function () {
   var types = this.types,
    dur = this.duration,
    lastType = findLast(types, function (type) {
     return dur._data[type];
    });

   // default template strings for each duration dimension type
   switch (lastType) {
    case "seconds":
     return "h:mm:ss";
    case "minutes":
     return "d[d] h:mm";
    case "hours":
     return "d[d] h[h]";
    case "days":
     return "M[m] d[d]";
    case "weeks":
     return "y[y] w[w]";
    case "months":
     return "y[y] M[m]";
    case "years":
     return "y[y]";
    default:
     return "y[y] M[m] d[d] h:mm:ss";
   }
  }
 };

})(this);
</script>
```