# Javascript Timezone Epoch

Tags: javascript

How to get current epoch time of a timezone (for example Asia/Calcutta) in javascript?
Using jstz library I am able to get timezone. But how to get epoch time for that timezone?

Comment: Doesn't this get you epoch? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707333/javascript-convert-date-time-string-to-epoch

Comment: new Date(moment.tz("Asia/Calcutta")).valueOf();

Comment: Is this correct? using moment js

Comment: try using moment.js

Comment: the moment.js documentation is very good