# convert ISO_String date (different format) time into epoch time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am getting time in `iso_string` format, not completely `iso_string` but something like this : `20180410T11:55:37+0000`

I know that there should be two hyphens in the above date but I'm getting this from my Spring service that returns Java `toLocaleDate().format(Date.ISO_String)`
date.

I tried to convert this format using `new Date('20180410T11:55:37+0000').getTime()`

But I got `NaN`

Is there any way to get this date converted into epoch in javascript so that I can easily use it in my front-end service?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Convert Date Time string to Epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707333/javascript-convert-date-time-string-to-epoch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the format will be like this then you could fix it before you create the Javascript `Date` object.

```
var rawDate = "20180410T11:55:37+0000";
var newRawDate = `${rawDate.slice(0, 4)}-${rawDate.slice(4, 6)}-${rawDate.slice(6)}`;
// ^^ Using ES6 templating - use string concatenation if this isn't going to be available
var date = new Date(newRawDate);
// Tue Apr 10 2018 12:55:37 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

Comment: @grahamlyons - you should be slicing `rawDate` instead of `date`.