# How to convert a given date and time to epoch time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, epoch

I am trying to convert the date and time that is obtained from UI to epoch Time.

Please find my code below.

```
function calculateEpoch(){ 
    var date = 11/1/2019 //obtained from ui
    var time = 11:00 //obtained from ui
    var date1 = date +"" + time;

    var someDate = new Date(date1);
    console.log("someDate : ",someDate) //getting error like Invalid Date
    someDate1 = someDate.getTime();
    console.log("someDate : ",someDate1) //getting error like someDate1 is not defined
    return someDate1 ;
}
```

Could anyone please help me with the working code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707333/javascript-convert-date-time-string-to-epoch/13707414 try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `" "`instead of `""` in `var date1 = date +" " + time;` It will work

```
function calculateEpoch(){ 
var date = '11/1/2019' //obtained from ui
    var time = '11:00' //obtained from ui
    var date1 = date +" " + time; // <---add space here

    var someDate = new Date(date1);
    console.log("someDate : ",someDate) //getting error like Invalid Date
    someDate1 = someDate.getTime();
    console.log("someDate : ",someDate1) //getting error like someDate1 is not defined
 return someDate1 ;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function calculateEpoch(){ 
    var date = '11/1/2019' //obtained from ui
    var time = '11:00' //obtained from ui
    var date1 = `${date} ${time}`; // add a space in between the date and time,
    // your date1 was invalid because it 11/1/2019:11:00

    var someDate = new Date(date1);
    console.log("someDate : ",someDate) //getting error like Invalid Date
    someDate1 = someDate.getTime();
    console.log("someDate : ",someDate1) //getting error like someDate1 is not defined
    return someDate1 ;
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Your first 2 lines of `date` and `time` are obtained from ui so I assume that's not the problem here. (They should be string)

The problem is with `date1`.

You have: `11/1/201911:00` **Invalid**

Should be: `11/1/2019 11:00`

You were almost there but you only needed to add a space between `date` and `time`.

```js
function calculateEpoch(){ 
    var date = '11/1/2019'; //obtained from ui
    var time = '11:00'; //obtained from ui
    var date1 = date + " " + time;

    var someDate = new Date(date1);
    console.log("someDate : ", someDate) //getting error like Invalid Date
    someDate1 = someDate.getTime();
    console.log("someDate : ", someDate1) //getting error like someDate1 is not defined
    return someDate1;
}
calculateEpoch();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way of doing it where the connection to the UI and the Date construction parameters are explicit:

```
function calculateEpoch() {
    var year = new Number(document.getElementById('uiYear').value);
    var month = new Number(document.getElementById('uiMonth').value) - 1;
    var day = new Number(document.getElementById('uiDay').value);
    var hours = new Number(document.getElementById('uiHour').value);
    var minutes = new Number(document.getElementById('uiMinute').value);
    var seconds = new Number(document.getElementById('uiSecond').value);
    var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, 0);
    var millis = d.getTime();
    return millis
}
```

This function (under a different name) can actually be seen in action together with its UI at https://currentmillis.com on the right-hand side.

Note that the month parameter of this Date constructor is zero-based (January is 0, December is 11): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax