# how to convert this string "09-March-2018" into Unix timestamp in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var stardate = "02-March-2016";
```

How to convert the stardate string into UNIX timestamp. Is there is any inbuilt function in javascript for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: You can do `new Date("02-March-2016").getTime()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Convert Date Time string to Epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707333/javascript-convert-date-time-string-to-epoch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the unix-timestamp do this:

```
new Date("02-March-2016").getTime() / 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, new Date("02-March-2016").getTime() / 1000;  . This thing is worked, but I have a question when I convert date to Unix Timestamp using this above code the result is slightly different from PHP inbuilt function "strtotime" time, why?

Comment: How does it differ?

Comment: I mean to say that is why JavaScript and PHP is giving different results, while both have to do the same kind of work.

Comment: What are these differences in the results? Can you give an example?