# Covert date to epoch timestamp using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have date in MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM format
Example 07/27/2022 10:36 AM
I want to convert it into Epoch timestamp which is 1658898360

Comment: your  Epoch timestamp `1658898360` is wrong, this value came from an unknown time zone

Comment: I just need a epoch timestamp of current time. My system.time is datetime in below format Wed, 27 Jul 2022 11:06:47 GMT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Convert Date Time string to Epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707333/javascript-convert-date-time-string-to-epoch)

Comment: **1658898360** is **GMT: Wednesday, 27 July 2022 5:06:00** so 5 hours and 30 minutes

Comment: So may be **Indian Standard Time (IST)**

Comment: It seems to be in IST only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `date.getTime` method to convert it to epoch:

```js
const date = new Date("07/27/2022 10:36 AM");
console.log(date.getTime() / 1000)
```

Just be sure that you (or the client) is in the same timezone you are expecting (IST in this case).

Or just add GMT+5:30 to ensure this.

```js
const date = new Date("07/27/2022 10:36 AM GMT+5:30");
console.log(date.getTime() / 1000)
```

Comment: The code snippet which you have provided has worked

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` object in Javascript is notoriously tricky to work with, and date parsing is sadly lacking. Simply using

```js
const dateString = "07/27/2022 10:36 AM"
const date = new Date(dateString)
```

*might* work, but not reliably.

One option is to use the [`date-fns` library](https://date-fns.org/):

```js
import { parse, getUnixTime } from 'date-fns'

const date = parse('07/27/2022 10:36 AM', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a', new Date())
const epoch = getUnixTime(date)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use below sample code:

```js
function epoch (date) {
  return Date.parse(date)
}    
const dateToday = new Date() 
const timestamp = epoch(dateToday)

console.log( timestamp )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62258341/3768239 what the difference with this answer ?