# i want to convert normal timestamp to long(epoc) in wso2 esb,i dont know java how to write javascript in script mediator can any one help me?

Tags: wso2-esb

```
 <inSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" onError="fault">
   <property name="CONTENT_TYPE" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
   <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
   <payloadFactory>
      <format>
         <getalert xmlns=""/>
      </format>
   </payloadFactory>
   <send receive="Get_Alert_Mobile_seq">
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/tlog_DataService//" format="soap11"/>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
   <script language="js">
      <![CDATA[var x="2012-04-04 17:19:48+05:30".tostring();var y=x.split("T");var z=y[0].tostring().split("-");var a=y[1].tostring().split(":");var d=new date(z[0],z[1],z[2],a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3].tostring().split("+")[0]);]]></script>
      <log level="custom">
         <property name="TIMESTAMP" expression="get-property('newdate')"/>
      </log>
      <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
      <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
      <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <log level="full"/>
   </inSequence>
```

i am using script mediator that i write inline also,and my timestamp is like this 2012-04-04 17:19:48+05:30 in DB

Answer (score 0):

I think following like will help you. 
[Converting UTC string to epoch time in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680025/converting-utc-string-to-epoch-time-in-javascript)

But it will be easier for you to write a custom mediator for the WSO2 ESB to get this done. It is a simple java class. Following link will help you on writing a custom mediator. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Writing+a+WSO2+ESB+Mediator

You can set the date string as a message property. Then access it from the custom mediator and convert it to long value of milliseconds. Then set the long value as another message property.