# How to convert this kind of date to epoch format?

Tags: javascript, html, date, epoch

I have just made an HTML input which returns the following type of date :

```
2017-02-05T15:00
```

How can i input it in the epoch format ?

Comment: Have a look at https://momentjs.com/, it's pretty much the go to for this sort of thing. Also, if you want to try it manually (don't see why you would...): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680025/converting-utc-string-to-epoch-time-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting UTC string to epoch time in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680025/converting-utc-string-to-epoch-time-in-javascript)

Comment: Could you share some more of your code?

Comment: I have found the solution. Date.parse(...) was enough. Sorry for my question, i was too speed for asking this.

Comment: @TotorAndMimine—you should ether close the question, or post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to convert this kind of date in Epoch format, you just have to do it :

```
var t1 = Date.parse("2017-02-05T15:00");
```